# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar un código a varios archivos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un código que lo he podido hacer ya con dos archivos en si copiandolo y solo cambiando el nombre del otro archivo, pero al querer aplicarlo digamos con 20 archivos, me va a generar muchísimas lineas, ¿como lo puedo resumir para que lo aplique a todos los 20 archivos?? el código es el siguiente solo lo tengo con dos archivos pero quiero agregar mas los archivos se llaman 1,2,3,4,etc hasta el 20:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


datos=pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(datos)
df=datos.iloc[:,[2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]

writer=ExcelWriter('exportado.xlsx')

datos=pd.read_csv('2.csv')
df2=pd.DataFrame(datos)
df2=datos.iloc[:,[2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='OK1',header=True, index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='OK2',header=True, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los archivos están nombrados exactamente de `1.csv` a `20.csv` puedes leerlos y salvarlos dentro de un ciclo:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

with pd.ExcelWriter('exportado.xlsx') as writer:
    for i in range(1, 20+1, 1):
        filename = '{0}.csv'.format(i)
        try:
            datos=pd.read_csv(filename)
            df=datos.iloc[:,[2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]
            df.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, header=True, index=False, sheet_name="Ok{0}".format(i), encoding='utf-8')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("El archivo {0} no existe".format(filename))

writer.save()
```

- Con `for i in range(1, 20+1, 1)`hacemos un ciclo de 1 a 20.
- Nota que estamos aprovechando el context manager con `with pd.ExcelWriter('exportado.xlsx') as writer` lo cual permite una finalización más controlada.
- Agregamos un bloque `try ... except` para controlar la excepción `FileNotFoundError` en caso que no existiera alguno de los archivos

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio funcionó a la perfección, una ultima pregunta, suponiendo que no me llega alguna información y me falta un archivo, digamos el '3.csv' como le puedo hacer para que continúe trabajando con los demás archivos aunque ese dato no me lo ponga???

Comment: @Arturok2099, pues, podemos usar un control de excepciones, verifica mi última edición

Answer (score 0):

Agregándole un poco al código de @Patricio Moracho, para poder revisar todos los archivos '.csv' que tengas en tu directorio puedes usar el siguiente código. Ten en cuenta que tienes que usar el módulo 'os', lo cual no será ningún problema pues es un módulo que forma parte de la librería estandard de Python. Con esto te evitas darte a la tarea de definir el límite para el rango del ciclo **for** o bien tener que programar alguna excepción por si no encuentra el fichero 3.csv dentro de una serie de ficheros 1.csv, 2.csv... n.csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

import os
PATH = './'

fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)

fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]

with pd.ExcelWriter('exportado.xlsx') as writer:
    for f in fileNames:
        df=pd.read_csv(f)
        sname = f.replace(".csv","")
        df.to_excel(writer,startrow=0, 
                    header=True, 
                    index=False, 
                    sheet_name="Ok"+sname, 
                    encoding='utf-8')

writer.save()
```

La variable 'PATH' es donde vas a buscar todos los archivos que deseas. La siguiente línea de código le asignará a 'fileNames' una lista con todos los directorios y ficheros (sin importar la extensión de los archivos) dentro de la ruta que asignaste en 'PATH'. La siguiente línea de código le asignará a 'fileNames' una lista con el nombre de todos los ficheros con extensión '.csv', la cual es definida en la expresión:

```
[file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]
```

Posteriormente, iteras a través de esta lista y a cada nombre de fichero le reemplazas la extensión por un string vacío para quedarte con el nombre y concatenarlo a 'Ok' para así tener tu nombre de Hoja en Excel.

**Consejo**

Si el archivo que quieres obtener de salida es con extensión '.csv' entonces deberás darle como parámetro a pd.ExcelWriter("NombreDeAlgunDirectorio/archivo.csv") la ruta del fichero '.csv' que quieres crear, dentro de un directorio. Esto con el motivo de no leer ese fichero si se ejecuta el script de Python de nuevo (ya que este programa leerá todos los ficheros '.csv').

Comment: Hola @tastycode, me funciono a la perfeccion haciendolo con los archivos csv que tengo, muchas gracias por su ayuda!!!!!!